# How to troubleshoot VPN packet issues?

Tags: vpn, networking, packet-loss, f5

I'm a web developer (10 yrs), and am tech savy, but don't know a lot about networking, so please forgive my ignorance. I work from home, so I'm always on my company VPN.

Over the last several weeks I've the following intermittent connection issues while on VPN for my work using the Big-IP Edge Client on a macbook pro.

1) For a week or two, I'd get intermittent connectivity drops. My VPN client would show that **Inbound Traffic** had 0kb/s throughput, but my **Outbound traffic** was normal at ~580kb/s. This would happen throughout the day at random times, but would usually last 30-60 seconds (very annoying for video conference calls).

My assumption was that inbound only packet loss would mean that VPN was the culprit. I called my help desk at work, and they claimed it was my ISP. I tried tethering to my phone (during one of the outage times, and it appeared to resolve the issue).

2) This last week I'm getting a lot of sporadic connectivity drops across both **Inbound** and **Outbound** traffic on VPN. The first issue hasn't shown up in several weeks. These drops are shorter (5-10) seconds, but very disruptive when I'm on a video call with my team.

**My questions**
1) What's the best way to troubleshoot these issues, and to see if it's a VPN or a ISP issue? Wireshark? Little snitch? Is there a way to test, or is it obvious? Is there a way to log packet loss on a given day?
2) Any recommendations for how to fix this?
3) I've been considering springing for Comcast Business internet since they have SLAs for connectivity. Any suggestions or experience on this front?

Thank you!

PS: unrelated note. I was downloading something on steam, and noticed that VPN was saying 85MB/s throughput, but steam was saying 10.3MB/s throughput. I used iStat to verify that nothing else was taking up bandwidth, and iStat confirmed 10.3MB/s throughput. What's going on there?

Comment: Hello Jamis, the best way would be having your IT support to investigate this, you will need the logs of the VPN endpoint and performing tests from this endpoint.  Regarding your P.S. you are confusing MB (Mega Bytes) with Mb (Mega Bits). A byte = 8 bits.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su], but if the problem is in your ISP, there is nothing anyone but the ISP can do about it.

Comment: @RonMaupin Understood. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the logs in a way when the issue is in live.

Try to Run wireshark on your Laptop, ask them to collect the logs and at the same time if you can try to ping any global IP like (8.8.8.8). You then compare the packets based on the sequence number that the packets forwarded from their end are reaching at you or not.

If packets from far end are not reaching at you even after they forward it then there can be 2 issue

> Either their ISP is not forwarding it to your ISP 
>   If their ISP is forwarding it and your ISP is receiving it then you need to verify if your ISP is forwarding it or not by asking your ISP about this

If they are confirming that they are forwarding those packets and still you are not receiving it you may check on your location upstream from where you can sniff the packets and check where it is getting dropped.

Hope this will provide a basic idea about the direction to look for resolving your issue.